# How to manipulate domain?

Tags: manipulate

I'm trying to view these functions as the scale goes from local to global. I don't want to manipulate the function, just the domain range.

```
Manipulate[Plot[{x^2,2^x} {x, 0, 10}], {x, 0, 10}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
Plot[{x^2, 2^x}, {x, 0, a}],
 {a, 10, 20}]
```

Answer (score 2):

This option also allows you to manipulate the function range and the default point of the domain

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[{x^2, 2^x}, {x, c, a}, 
  PlotRange -> {-100 - b, 900 + b}], {{a, 15}, 10, 40}, {{b, 100}, 0, 
  200}, {{c, -30}, -100, 200}]
```